# Property does not get filled within dependency jar (Spring 3 / XML)

Tags: java, xml, spring, properties, applicationcontext

We have a Spring managed application that uses another jar as a dependency, which contains a Spring managed service class, that need to use some value injected from property file

The main application with the Spring context setup

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  GenericXmlApplicationContext appContext = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
  SomeClass someClass = (SomeClass) appContext.getBean("someClass");
  someClass.someMethod();
  ...
```

The class which calls the service from the dependent jar

```
public class SomeClass {
  private ServiceFromTheOtherJar serviceFromTheOtherJar;

  public SomeClass(ServiceFromTheOtherJar serviceFromTheOtherJar) {
    this.serviceFromTheOtherJar = serviceFromTheOtherJar;
  }

  public void someMethod() {
    serviceFromTheOtherJar.call();
    ...
```

The applicationContext.xml of the main app

```
<bean name="serviceFromTheOtherJar" class="com...ServiceFromTheOtherJar"/>

<bean name="someClass" class="com...SomeClass">
    <constructor-arg ref="serviceFromTheOtherJar"/>
</bean>
```

The service class in the dependent jar

```
public class ServiceFromTheOtherJar {

  private String someFieldWeWantToFillFromPropertyFile;

  public void setSomeFieldWeWantToFillFromPropertyFile(String someFieldWeWantToFillFromPropertyFile) {
    this.someFieldWeWantToFillFromPropertyFile = someFieldWeWantToFillFromPropertyFile;
  }

  public void call() {
    //we would like to use the filled someFieldWeWantToFillFromPropertyFile here
    ...
```

And of course we have an application.properties file in the dependent jar, that contains the property value that we would like to inject into someFieldWeWantToFillFromPropertyFile

Now we can add the dependent jar as a dependency to the main app; when the main app is being executed then its Spring context is getting set up all right, and ServiceFromTheOtherJar.call() method gets called as expected; however someFieldWeWantToFillFromPropertyFile does not get filled from the property file whatever we tried so far (e.g. @PropertySource({"application.properties"}), Environment.getProperty(...) etc.)

Restrictions

- We have Spring 3 version in both jars, and that has to remain so due to the deployment environment; so Spring 4 solutions are out of question
- As you see above, the main app currently uses GenericXmlApplicationContext and changing that seem to indicate a significant rewriting of the application. Therefore e.g. it seemed to be not possible to use @Service annotation on ServiceFromTheOtherJar because it caused BeanCreationException during the execution and context setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read values from property file you have to add the following bean to applicationContext.xml.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:application.properties" />
</bean>
```

Assuming the application.properties-file contains a definition like this

```
myValue=Hello World
```

the definition of the service-bean should by extended like this

```
<bean name="serviceFromTheOtherJar" class="com...ServiceFromTheOtherJar">
    <property name="someFieldWeWantToFillFromPropertyFile" value="${myValue}" />
</bean>
```

Now Spring will look for the application.properties-file in classpath and set the attribute of the service bean according to myValue.

Comment: It works, thank you. But I wonder if it's also OK from architectural/sw principles point of view? I mean here the main jar accesses the dependency jar's property file and manages the injection; I found annotation solutions where it's all handled within the dependency jar: has own Configuration/ComponentScan file, and the Service class manages the injection with Value. Unfortunately I couldn't figure out a working XML solution; e.g. main jar can import the dependency jar's own XML context which declares the service bean+property injection, but during the execution the injection doesn't happen..

Comment: It's possible to define the context for the service bean and the other beans for reading the properties in an own xml file (service-context.xml) which is located in the dependency jar. The file defining the main context can include the other file with `<import resource="classpath:service-context.xml" />`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I referred in my previous comment as tried but not working for some reason. It compiles and the context buildup is succesful, but the property value does not get injected during the execution..

Comment: Does your context contains a bean of type `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`? If it is missing the value won't be read from the properties file. Do you try to access the correct properties file? If you rename it for a quick test an `java.io.FileNotFoundException` should be thrown.

Comment: Good hint, thank you. Apparently we missed a properly declared PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean from the dependency jar; after it has been declared, the problem seems to be resolved.